# Syntax error in pandas dataframe when including bitwise operations for completeness count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get a count of completeness in each column for my pandas dataframe but I am getting a syntax error:

```
record["CompleteCount"] = len((df_table1[df_table1[column]!= "") & (df_table1[column]).notnull()].loc[:,column])
```

It is pointing to the closing bracket after `""` as where the error occurs, but I get this error without the parentheses and using `'and'` instead of `&`:

> typeerror: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type
>   [bool]

My definition of completeness is any cell that is not empty and not null.

What is the correct syntax to make this code work?

Comment: notnull() will return a series of boolean values and other condition will check just one row. you may change other condition to like `df_table1[column])!=np.Nan`

Comment: Thanks, I now get this error after changing to np.Nan: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [float]

Comment: Parentheses are not closed properly.`(df_table1[df_table1[column]!= "")` Look at square bracket and round bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the location of the row

```
 df.loc[(df_table1[column]!= "") & (df_table1[column]!=np.nan)]
```

OR replace empty string with nan

```
df_table1[column].replace('',np.nan)
df[df_table1[column].notnull()]
```

Comment: This makes the command run but it is very, very slow. Hasn't stopped running yet. Dataset is only c. 1000 rows.

Comment: you can also replace the empty string with nan. updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of elements that respect your constraints, this should work:

```
((df_table1[column] != "") & (df_table1[column].notnull())).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on this line of code but it throwing up a syntax error on the line of code below it: record["EmptyCount"] = len(df_table1[df_table1[column]==""].loc[:,column])  why is this?

Comment: This line apparently looks ok, from the syntax point of view. Maybe the syntax error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I think it is somewhere else but I don't know where because before the line above it ran ok.